# typescript: Cannot find module 'react'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I don't understand why it can't find it.

```
$ cat tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "types": [
      "lodash",
      "react",
      "react-dom"
    ]
  }
}

$ tree node_modules/@types

node_modules/@types/
├── lodash
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   └── types-metadata.json
├── react
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── index.d.ts
│   ├── package.json
│   └── types-metadata.json
└── react-dom
    ├── README.md
    ├── index.d.ts
    ├── package.json
    ├── server.d.ts
    └── types-metadata.json
```

Importing in a component file.

```
// src/components/component.tsx

import * as React from "react";
```

What gives?

Comment: The output from running with `--traceResolution` would be helpful

Answer (score 29, accepted):

if you're not using typescript 2.1, you should upgrade to it.  it looks like you're using a 2.x version from the @types you have there.

here is a working `tsconfig.json` file that i'm using right now:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noResolve": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

it's been a couple days since i resolved the same issue you were having, but i think the key here is the `"moduleResolution": "node"` and `"allowJs": true`.

Answer (score 63):

I had the same issue. You just need to install @types:

```
npm i -D @types/react
```

Comment: Which, for absolute n00bs (me) is the same as `npm install --save-dev @types/react`. From [the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install): "*-D, --save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.*"

Comment: https://yarnpkg.com/package/@types/react worked for me as I use Yarn.

Answer (score 8):

As on version 2.4.* the responsible config entry of this error (in most of the cases) is:

```
"compilerOptions": {
          ...
          "moduleResolution": "node" <---------- this entry
          ...
}
```

Comment: What's the solution then?

Answer (score 8):

For resolving the typescript "Cannot find module 'react'", which comes from eslint rules,

You need to install `@types/react` :

`$ npm i -D @types/react`

or

`$ yarn add -D @types/react`

And in your ".eslintrc" file add in `extends` array the react plugin:

```
...
extends: [
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        ...  
],
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue. In my case disabling [deno extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=justjavac.vscode-deno) solved the problem. It was somehow messing with the imports.

Answer (score 4):

If you are joining a project that was started by someone else, it is likely that the repo already has the proper `devDependencies` listed (e.g. `@types/react`) in `package.json`. You just need to initiate them with:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed `@types/react` and it still doesn't work, I recommend that you use a recent version of `Typescript` and then close your IDE/editor, delete `node_modules` folder, and run `npm install` or `yarn install` and check it again. it should work now.

Answer (score 1):

At the point in time of writing this comment, I saw an error on my cmd saying that I do not have typescript installed.

```
npm install typescript
```

and it did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Also check to see if your node_modules is present. If it is and you are still experiencing this problem, delete it and reinstall it by running npm install. This solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue with types :

```
npm i -D @types/react or yarn add @types/react
```

More over my tsconfig.json "jsx" parameter was changing from "react" to "react-jsx" automatically at yarn start.
If it can help are is my tsconfig which works for me:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noResolve": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "./node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm i @types/react` or `yarn add @types/react`will solve the issue. The error is occurring due to missing react types

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `node_modules`package and `yarn_lock` file (if you have any). Then try a `yarn install` and restart your VS Code. Worked for me perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that developer might want to try on Windows if none of these answers work. Sometimes you have multiple users on your device having different permissions, and mostly you are obliged to use the user with non-admin permissions. In this case, some folders that are accessible to admins only (modules you are importing into the project) are not accessible to users. Solution: Run VS Code with administrator privileges.

Answer (score 0):

```
i am writing for `react-native` assuming you have used `babel-plugin-module-resolver` and all your code is inside src folder <br />
These are the files required to be configured in-order to work on absolute imports in typescript<br />

1. babel.config.js add the module-resolver plugin as below <br/>
`module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./'],
        alias: {
          src: './src',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};`

2. update ts config with below code <br />
 `"baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src": ["src/*"],
      "tests": ["tests/*"]
    },`

3. then all your import will starts with src for example. `import funkyImage from src/images/funkyImage.png`
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue when i was working with Nextjs. The issue was resolve with types/react version 18.0.1.

```
npm install --save-dev @types/react@18.0.1
```

Answer (score -15):

```
const React = require("react");
```

This fixed the issue.