# How to write the tests for a React Native library for DefinitelyTyped?

Tags: typescript, react-native, typescript-typings, definitelytyped, type-declaration

I wanted to contribute to the [rn-placeholder](https://github.com/mfrachet/rn-placeholder) library for React Native by providing the types for [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). This is my first time contributing an `index.d.ts` file to DefinitelyTyped.

I wrote the declaration file. Now I want to write the mandatory `rn-placeholder-tests.ts` file. But when I try to use my declarations I get `regexp` errors:

```
[ts]
Conversion of type 'RegExp' to type 'View' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Property 'measure' is missing in type 'RegExp'.
```

I even tried just duplicating tests from `@types/react-native` and they give the same errors:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from "react-native";

class CustomView extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <View />
  }
}
```

Here is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["es6"],
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "baseUrl": "../",
        "typeRoots": ["../"],
        "types": [],
        "noEmit": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
    },
    "files": ["index.d.ts", "rn-placeholder-tests.ts"]
}
```

The other files are just how they are generated when using `npx dts-gen --dt --name my-package-name --template module`.

How can I get the tests to pass?

**EDIT:** I converted the `rn-placeholder-tests.ts` to `.tsx` which gets rid of the `regexp` error. But now TSLint complains that it can't find the modules:

```
[ts] Cannot find module 'react'.
[ts] Cannot find module 'react-native'.
[ts] Cannot find module 'rn-placeholder'.
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the .ts to .tsx is the right move as far as the file extension. (See more info here about tsx: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html)

For the other "Cannot find module" errors, see this ["typescript: Cannot find module 'react'" issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899868/typescript-cannot-find-module-react).

It could be that  you need to add the type definitions:

```
npm i -D @types/react
```

Or, perhaps you simply need to add "moduleResolution" to your tsconfig.json file:

```
"compilerOptions": {
          ...
          "moduleResolution": "node" <---------- this entry
          ...
}
```