# VSCode TS2307 Cannot find module

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, tsc

Opening a Typescript project in VSCode causes error "ts2307 Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations". But Webstorm works fine. I created the repo from CRA, the typescript template. Node installed via nvm. I'm using yarn 3.2.3 here and I have not ejected the CRA.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "frontend-ts",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40899868/typescript-cannot-find-module-react)

Answer (score 2):

yarn3 new version, need extra config for vscode which fix this editor issue
please ref below three link:

- https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/typescript/typescript-compiling#_using-newer-typescript-versions
- https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#vscode
- https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

==fix step=================

1. create yarn workspace
2. yarn (in workspace)
3. yarn dlx @yarnpkg/sdks vscode
4. vscode select workspace typescript //https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/editor-sdks#vscode
5. vscode will advise use install zipfs extension, insall it(maybe use can install zipfs by your self)

Comment: Good call on the yarn/typescript/vscode getting started. Setting the workspace typescript did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `npm i --save-dev @types/react`

Comment: I believe it's already there? I added the package.json to my question.

Comment: Then try deleting node_modules folder and then do `npm install` again.

Comment: I believe i'm using yarn 3.2.3. I've now deleted node_modules, ran yarn install, but nothing changes and no new node_modules folder appears. Now tried removing yarn cache and reinstalling. Still same error as in question.

Comment: Then you need to do `yarn`. Also make sure you delete node_ modules folder, package-lock.json file and yarn.lock file before doing `yarn`

Comment: I don't have node_modules folder. I assume node_modules appears if I were to use npm, but I use yarn. So I also therefore don't have package-lock.json. I have yarn.lock, which I removed. Tried `yarn install` but same error remains.

Comment: I suspect this is a VSCode config issue, since webstorm works fine.

Comment: I doubt that. Make sure ".eslintrc" file has/add in extends array the react plugin:
...
extends: [
        'plugin:react/recommended',
        ...  
],

Comment: If you have tried everything. Also you could try restarting your vscode. That might help!

Comment: I think you might be on to something with .eslintrc! I forgot about that file. In fact it does not exist. I could try create one manually, but when I try to crate it through VS Code's Command Panel "Create ESLint Configuration", the VSCode terminal output is `zsh: command not found: eslint`. And running `which eslint` in terminal doesn't find eslint. It seems eslint is not installed...

Comment: Try creating manually. And also try vscode restart.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I missed the concept of Yarn workspaces. As soon as I implemented [this](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2019/07/yarn-workspaces-organize-project-codebase-pro/), it was solved! Workspaces allows node_modules to exist somewhere and satisfy VSCode.